# Why MySql is saving only first character of the string? (I am using python 3)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, insert

I am trying to save a random generated code in MySql db but it saves only the first character, I tried different approached but none worked. This is my code:

```
try:
    error = None
    with mysql.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        passwordd = ''
        if request.method == 'GET' or 'POST':
            for n in range(0, 8):
                x = random.randint(0, 9)
                if x <= 3:
                    passwordd += str(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'))
                elif x <= 6:
                    passwordd += str(random.choice('abcffsddddd'))
                else:
                    passwordd += str(random.randrange(0, 9))
                    return passwordd
                sql = "INSERT INTO generatedcode(password) VALUES (%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, (passwordd))
                mysql.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Bear in mind that your sql insert is in every `n` loop! and if `x` is neither less then 3 or less then 6, it will `return password` and no sql insert will happen.

Comment: @IronFist thank you for the response but actually it inserts. However, it inserts only the first character, not the whole string! I actually realized its in N loop so thats why it saves only one but when I tried to move it outside of the loop then it doesnt save anything to DB !

Comment: The problem here is `x = random.randint(0, 9)`, probably most of the results are greater than 6, which leads to no write to your DB, or may be you have a `return` or `break` expression below `mysql.connection.commit()`, which breaks the loop !

Comment: @IronFist thanks for helping but I figured out what the problem was. I will upload my fix below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION TO IT:

```
passwordd = ''

    if request.method == 'GET' or 'POST':

        for n in range(0, 8):

            x = random.randint(0, 9)
            if x <= 3:
                passwordd += str(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'))
            elif x <= 6:
                passwordd += str(random.choice(',.;:-_*%&/()=?!'))
            else:
                passwordd += str(random.randrange(0, 9))

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO generatedcode(password) VALUES (%s)", [passwordd])
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return passwordd
```